# simple asp.net autocompleteExtender not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

I'm currently having some trouble with ajax autoCompleteExtender.

.Aspx file

```
  <asp:toolkitscriptmanager runat="server" ID ="scropt" EnablePageMethods ="true" EnablePartialRendering ="true">
        </asp:toolkitscriptmanager>


        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" MinimumPrefixLength="2" TargetControlID ="TextBox1" 
            ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" runat="server"  CompletionInterval ="100"></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

.Aspx.cs file

```
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("prefix:" + prefixText);
            List<string> list = new List<string>();

            list.Add("hello");
            list.Add("world");
            list.Add("everyone");

            return list.ToArray();
        }
```

The intended behavior of this code was to have a textbox dropdown a list of string values return upon entering 2 letters into the textbox. However this is not happening. I used fiddler to track my http request and realised that the textbox was not firing any http requests to the server. Does anyone know the cause of this or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: I think you are using an outdated version of toolkitscriptmanager..try using  latest ajax toolkit and use scriptmanager instead of toolkitscritptmanager

Comment: did you check this with asp.net script manager control.please check this link it may be helpful for you.http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-AutoCompleteExtender-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

@weejing i run your code it is work perfectly.
if any confusion you copy my code.

**aspx code**

```
 <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" MinimumPrefixLength="1" TargetControlID ="TextBox1" 
                ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" runat="server" CompletionInterval ="100">
    </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
        </form>
    </body>
```

**aspx.cs code**

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("prefix:" + prefixText);
            List<string> list = new List<string>();

            list.Add("hello");
            list.Add("world");
            list.Add("everyone");

            return list.ToArray();
        }
```